# How to customize django's UserCreationForm?

Tags: django, authentication

I want to customise the django.contrib.auth UserCreationForm to:

- Ignore the email field, and only display a user-name which must be an email address
- Prompt the user for first name and last name.

I'm using django-registration if that makes a difference.

How can I do this?

I can subclass the form, but how do I tell the auth system to use my version of the form instead of the default one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

http://dmitko.ru/?p=546